# What does this notation |_| mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation

I don't know what it is even called so I cannot really type it out properly, sorry.
I've seen things like $X$|_|$[0,1)$. The symbol in question looks like $\cup$ but without curvy, round bits, its like the bottom half of a square.

I don't know how else to describe it and it look bizarre.

Can anyone tell me? Thank you

Comment: Is it $\sqcup$? Or $\amalg$?

Comment: $\sqcup$ is typically used to denote disjoint union. Meaning, you take the union of copies of the sets in questions but without common elements. It is standard to "make the sets disjoint" by interpreting $A\sqcup B$ to mean $(A\times\{0\})\cup (B\times\{1\})$. Similarly for unions of more than two sets.

Comment: Also referred to as the "coproduct" in category theory.  See Lang's Algebra.

Comment: By the way you can use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to look up Latex symbols from a drawing of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\sqcup B$ is just $A\cup B$, but it gives the information that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, i.e. $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

In probability theory, this notation can also be used for independence.  For example, $X\sqcup Y$ means that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: That's the notation I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Not exactly, sometimes we define the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, i.e., $A\sqcup B=\{(a,0)\mid a\in A\}\cup\{(b,1)\mid b\in B\}$ which is well defined no matter $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.